Adjusting the width of graphics in a column
This may be a common issue but I can't seem to find a proper reference for it.
I want to draw multiple graphics, stacked in a column, such that the horizontal axis match exactly. For some obscure reason (I guess related to how much "extra" white space is added), I have to manually fiddle with the graphic widths, like in the example below, where one graphics must be 35 pixels wider than the other for the axes to appear as a good (and likely not a perfect...) match.
With[{ω0 = 72, α = 500},
 GraphicsColumn[{
   LogLogPlot[
    Abs[(I  ω)/(ω0^2 - ω^2 + 2 α  I)], {ω, 10^-1, 10^5}, ImageSize -> {500, Automatic}, Frame -> True],
   LogLinearPlot[
    Arg[(I  ω)/(ω0^2 - ω^2 + 2 α  I)], {ω, 10^-1, 10^5}, ImageSize -> {535, Automatic}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/3]}]
]


What is the proper/robust way to instruct Mathematica to make this alignement ?
Bonus question: the behavior seems to change if I use Column instead of GraphicsColumn (meaning that the width values that work for one don't work for the other), so the question extends to this variant too. Any hint on which method should be preferred is welcome.
Thanks.

Have you explored: PlotGrid yet?

There's also this question, but I think the answer might be outdated enough to be almost broken (I think I've made changes to it since then, with no version control).

You can use ImagePadding to specify the spacing around the plots and make them equal:
ω0=72;
α=500;
spec=Sequence[Frame->True,AspectRatio->Full,ImagePadding->{{30,5},{30,5}}];
GraphicsColumn[{
LogLogPlot[Abs[(I ω)/(ω0^2-ω^2+2 α I)],{ω,10^-1,10^5},Evaluate[spec],ImageSize->500],
LogLinearPlot[Arg[(I ω)/(ω0^2-ω^2+2 α I)],{ω,10^-1,10^5},Evaluate[spec],ImageSize->{500,160}]
}]

To have full control you have to use AspectRatio Full to make it fit the box that is specified by the ImageSize with a padding of ImagePadding. The 4 values of ImagePadding are for left/right, bottom/top paddings for both in this case, but can be altered.
Alternatively, with a little bit less control you can do this:
With[{ω0 = 72, α = 500}, 
 GraphicsColumn[{LogLogPlot[
    Abs[(I ω)/(ω0^2 - ω^2 + 
        2 α I)], {ω, 10^-1, 10^5}, Frame -> True], 
   LogLinearPlot[
    Arg[(I ω)/(ω0^2 - ω^2 + 
        2 α I)], {ω, 10^-1, 10^5}, Frame -> True, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/3]}, ImageSize -> 500]]

Specifying the size for the GraphicsColumn. Not for each plot individually.
